# Adding a HREF to a JQuery Dynamically Populated Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form based menu which automatically populates the select options with the contents of a primary-nav UL. It wonderfully increments the  with dashes reflecting the  positions of the menu.

However, it doesn't populate the  with the HREFs of the links within the ULs.

This is the code that I have:

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
                var options = '<option selected></option>';

                $('#primary-nav').find('a').each(function () {
                    var text = $(this).text(),
                    depth = $(this).parent().parents('ul').length,
                    depthChar = '',
                    i = 1;
                    for (i; i < depth; i++) { depthChar += '&ndash;&nbsp;';
                        }
                    options += '<option>' + depthChar + text + '</option>';
                });
                $('<select id=\'mobile-menu\' />').append(options).appendTo('#mobile-nav');

                $("#primary-nav select").change(function() {
                    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                });

            });


        </script>
```

I need to somehow add the below to the above so that when clicked the selected option goes to a url, and not a url based on the displayed value;

```
$("#primary-nav a").each(function() {
var el = $(this);
$("<option />", {
 "value"   : el.attr("href"),
"text"    : el.text()
}).appendTo("#primary-nav select");
});
```

Can anyone advise me how I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the value attribute in your current code:

```
$('#primary-nav').find('a').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        href = $(this).attr('href'),
        depth = $(this).parent().parents('ul').length,
        depthChar = '',
        i = 1;
    for (i; i < depth; i++) {
        depthChar += '&ndash;&nbsp;';
    }
    options += '<option value="'+href+'">' + depthChar + text + '</option>';
});
$('<select id=\'mobile-menu\' />').append(options).appendTo('#mobile-nav');
```